# Custom Error page isn't loading when URL contains "/ /"

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-403, errordocument

I'm having a very specific issue with a site I'm building that is set up to use friendly URLs and custom error pages. I've been reading the message boards for days and although there are a lot of similar seeming posts, nothing addresses this problem specifically... at least to my newbie eyes.

Mostly everything on my site is running ok:

- URLs like "example.com/main/variable/variable" work just fine (redirects to example.com/index.php, loads main.php internally, and pulls the variables into an array)
- 404 errors are handled by index.php and work fine
- 403 errors when you try to access a subfolder with no index page mostly work fine too: "example.com/folder" shows the custom 403 error page at 403.php

Where I'm running into trouble is if the URL gets corrupted to contain a single space followed by a forward slash:

- "example.com/ /" or "example.com/folder/ /"
- "example.com/%20/" or "example.com/folder/%20/"

When this happens a 403 error gets triggered but it doesn't load the custom 403.php page.

Noteably, this problem does *not* occur if the URL lacks the trailing slash:

- "example.com/ " or "example.com/%20"
- "example.com/folder/ " or "example.com/folder/%20"

These all trigger 404 errors rather than 403, which is what I would like to happen when the trailing slash is included.

I realize this is a very specific situation that will only occur if someone mangles a url while they're typing it in, but I would love for it to not happen. I talked with my web host and they said everything is correct on their end.

Here's the code I'm currently running in .htaccess in my /public-html/ directory:

```
ErrorDocument 403 https://www.example.com/403.php

# Begin EnforceSSL 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
</IfModule>
# End EnforceSSL

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

and here's the code in index.php which handles the friendly URLs:

```
<?php

// Create a URL array containing any passed variables, including requested page
$URL = explode("/", $_SERVER[QUERY_STRING]);

// Load the page
if (trim($URL[0]) == "index"){
    require_once("home.php");
} else if (trim(($URL[0]) == "")){
    require_once("home.php");           
} else if (file_exists(strtolower(trim($URL[0])).".php")) {
    require_once(strtolower(trim($URL[0])).".php");
} else {
    require_once("404.php");
}
?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: "a 403 error gets triggered" - What exactly are you seeing and where is this response coming from? A default 403 Apache response? _Aside:_ The way you have configured the `ErrorDocument` directive using an absolute URL-path, this will trigger a 302 redirect, not a 403 HTTP response code. You should be using a root-relative URL-path here instead.

Comment: @MrWhite Yes, it's just a default Apache response: "403 Forbidden  Forbidden You don't have permission to access / / on this server." Re: the URL-path, I had originally been using a relative path but thought maybe it wasn't finding the file, so I changed it. I've changed it back, but it doesn't affect the behavior.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it's just a default Apache response: "403 Forbidden Forbidden You don't have permission to access / / on this server."

There is likely a rule (mod_security perhaps) that is defined in the server config that is blocking such requests. The issue here is that the `ErrorDocument` defined in `.htaccess` is too late to serve your custom response. You would need to define the `ErrorDocument` *earlier* in the server config.

If you are on a shared server then you will need to contact your host to debug this further.

Comment: I suspected as much although I hoped there was something I could do about it... I guess I'll leave well enough alone for now. Thank you!